# No usr directory in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Surprised to know that it does not have usr directory
when i type the following command in terminal "cd usr"
error - no such file or directory

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try `cd /usr`.

The directory is off the root, and without the forward slash, you are changing directories to one below your current directory.

Comment: tried that to, but nothing works
i am not even able to find it in GUI

Comment: What is the output of `cd / && ls -l | grep usr` in the terminal? `du -sh /usr/` says
`5,1G /usr/` for me.

Comment: cd / && ls -l | grep usr gives drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Apr 17 06:51 usr and du -sh /usr/ shows 3.1G /usr/

Comment: You have just shown the results of two commands that have found `/usr`.  In what way do you mean that you can't see it?